# how i should correct this Java program?

Tags: java

I'm very amateur in Java programming. Please help me to correct this program because it has error in if loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyMultiplyProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOne = keyboardInput.nextInt();
        int numberTwo;
        if (numberTwo=1;numberOne*numberTwo<=1000;numberTwo++){
            System.out.println("The resault of "+numberOne+" * "+numberTwo+"is: "+(numberOne*numberTwo));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: semi colon in if statement

Comment: what you want to do ??

Comment: where should put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if** is not a loop. **for** is :

```
for (numberTwo=1;numberOne*numberTwo<=1000;numberTwo++){
    System.out.println("The resault of "+numberOne+" * "+numberTwo+"is: "+(numberOne*numberTwo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code helps

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOne = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    int numberTwo;
    for (numberTwo = 1; numberOne * numberTwo <= 1000; numberTwo++){
    System.out.println("The resault of " + numberOne + " * "
        + numberTwo + "is: " + (numberOne * numberTwo));
    }

}
```